# How to style multiples of 3 li elements

Tags: html, css

i want to style only multiple's of three "li" elements..
how to do it?

html:

```
 <div class="test">
 <ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
 </ul>

</div>
```

css:

```
 .test ul li:nth-child(n+3){background:#000;}
```

Comment: Why use addition for multiples? Use `:nth-child(3n)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by [`:nth-child(3n+3)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) or `:nth-child(3n)` if you want to start from third `li` element

```css
ul li:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background: blue;  
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
 </ul>
```

or `:nth-child(3n)` if you want to start from first element

```css
ul li:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
    <li>content</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
.test ul li:nth-child(3n) {
    background:#000;
}
```